# Images fail to render in react-native when using resizeMode="contain" props?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using reactnative for making an android app. I am using react native router flux for navigation between different pages of the app. (As the doc indicates by calling `Actions.PAGENAME()`).

When each page loads initially everything was quite good but the problem arises after navigating or browsing through different pages of the app for some time , Images starting to disappear. The places where I used image are blank in that case. Also when I reload the app several times in debug mode, same thing happen.

After trying for couple of days with lots of trial and error I had found that this issue is caused when I use `< Image >` component with props `resizeMode="contain"`. If I use `resizeMode="cover"` , the issue is not there. However, I need that props on order to place the image properly and it seems the only option.

Does any of you faced the same problem I am facing no ? Is there any solution to the problem? If not, then what is the alternative?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find out how to fix it?

Comment: Now I no longer work on react native @Pouya92 , this question was posted long ago, when react native is new. I don't follow much about react related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add android:largeHeap="true" in your android manifest application tag. Like the following stackoverflow-answer described. This seems to create better performance and may solve your image loading issues.

[React-native: image missing after reloading JS several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655189/react-native-image-missing-after-reloading-js-several-times)

Comment: Before posting the question I already go through the link and solution mentioned in your answer . But adding android:largeHeap="true" in android manifest file is causing app crash after several minutes of app usage. In that case images appear properly but the app was performing slow and eventually crash. So I think it was not the correct solution.