# Images disappear on Android (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

For an app that I'm making it's important that I have background images. These images render great on the first time they load. Here's an example of one image:

```
<View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: STATUSBAR_HEIGHT, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }}>
            <ImageBackground style={{ flex: 1 }}
                             resizeMode='stretch'
                             source={require('../../res/images/image.png')}>

                 // Children

            </ImageBackground>
</View>
```

But after navigating using react-navigation, the image stops loading. This doesn't happen consistently. Sometimes it happens after navigating back to this screen once and sometimes it won't happen until three or four times later.

This error only happens on Android.

How can I ensure that these images are loading. Is it possible for me to log when the image loads?

Thanks!

EDIT: Okay, so this seems to be an issue related to memory use. The smaller the image, the more loads it takes for it to eventually stop loading. Unfortunately, the onError prop for Image components doesn't allow me to log the actual error message, so I don't truly know what's going on.

Comment: Are you using expo? Did this happen only in production or in development too?

Comment: I am using expo. This happens in both production and development. @riwu

Comment: In production, you need to bundle the assets or it'll have to fetch from the internet every time. But if it happens in development too then I guess that's not the issue.

Comment: I have bundled the assets as well. This happened before and after I did that, unfortunately.

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34786001/3978308 . It's mandatory for you to use stretch?